# CSS Taglist for gedit 3.4

Tags: tags, gedit, ubuntu-12.04

How do we install/integrate CSS tag list in ubuntu 12.04, so that we can get the info of tags in the gedit text-editor?

Where to get the tags xml files from ? and where to place them ?

Does anyone have the relevant information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The !2.04 Precise Pangolin gedit default plug-in list release is crippled and amputated.

The robustness, reliability, integrity, consistency, ... of 12.04 ... NOT!

some refs.:

- https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins#available
- https://live.gnome.org/GeditPlugins
- https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gedit-plugins/   (12.04)
- https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/gedit-plugins/   (12.10)

  Gedit >> Edit >> Preferences >> Plugins

does not have "`Tag List`" (see first image)

contrary to the documented (see second image)

```
Gedit >> Edit >> Preferences >> Plugins >> Help >>
```

> gedit Plugins
>      Configure and use gedit Plugins

which states:

> ```
> Default gedit Plugins
>   Change case
>     Change the case of selected text
>   Document statistics
>     View document statistics
>   External tools
>   ...  
>   Sort
>     Sort lines of text into alphabetical order
>   Spell-check your document
>   Tag list
>     Automatically insert tags, strings and special characters into a document
> ```

Gedit plugin list

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Rw0.png]

contradicts:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu4zj.png]